# What is the best way to loop an AD query in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, active-directory

I have a macro in Excel that queries a computer name from Column A against Active Directory to determine whether the computer object is enabled or disabled.

Compared to PowerShell, it runs slowly. My code is calling a function with each loop iteration; this function queries AD for the computer object's useraccountcontrol flag. I'm wondering if there is a better way to write the macro so that it returns the result faster. I tried moving the `conn` and `cmd` objects out of the function and passing them in so they don't get recreated every time but it didn't seem to help.

This is what my code looks like at the moment:

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
    For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
        If Not IsEmpty(Cell) And Cell.Row > 1 Then
            Range("B" & Cell.Row).Value = GetComputerStatus(Range("A" & Cell.Row).Value)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function GetComputerStatus(ComputerName)
    Base = "<LDAP://myaddomain.com>"
    Query = "(&(objectClass=computer)(name=" & ComputerName & "))"
    attr = "useraccountcontrol"
    scope = "subtree"
    
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"
    
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = Base & ";" & Query & ";" & attr & ";" & scope
    
    Set rs = cmd.Execute
    Result = "Unknown"
    Do Until rs.EOF
        If rs.Fields("useraccountcontrol").Value And 2 Then
            Result = "Disabled"
        Else
            Result = "Enabled"
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close
    
    conn.Close
    
    GetComputerStatus = Result
End Function
```

Comment: Some general suggestions about the loop but not about the querying method. Try looping through just the known  number of filled rows in column `A` rather than looping through the entire column of `A:A`, using the `.Rows.Count`/`.End(xlUp)` method. Also, try assigning ranges to arrays for the loop and for the output. You can input/output arrays from/to a contiguous range in one fell swoop, e.g.,  `myArray=Range(“B2:B"&lnglastrow)`. Arrays tend to have faster access than reading directly from a range.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to search for many computers in each search instead of one at a time. You would build a search filter like this:

```
(&(objectClass=computer)(|(name=Computer1)(name=Computer2)(name=Computer3)))
```

I'll leave it to you to write that code in VBA, but if it helps (it may not), I have an example of doing that in C# here: [Active Directory: Better Performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html#ask-for-as-much-as-you-can-at-a-time)

The tricky part is that you may not get the results in the order that you expect, or may not get a result at all if the computer doesn't exist in AD. So you will have to ask it to return the `name` attribute along with `userAccountControl` so that you can match the right result with the right row in your spreadsheet.

```
attr = "name,useraccountcontrol"
```

There is a limit to how big a query can be, but I've used 50 at a time as an arbitrary limit and I haven't had any problems.